# How to iterate JSON with multiple levels?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Welcome, I got a problem with JSON file. I would like to iterate through it and get every status into array, but I got stuck. I load this file and parse it. Then I tried to use forEach but it did not worked. Thanks for help!

```
[{
  "offers": [{
    "advertiser_api_id": 12,
    "status": 1
  }, {
    "advertiser_api_id": 13,
    "status": 0
  }]
}]
```

Comment: Do you want to extract all status values into a new array? meaning for the above example you will get `[1, 0]`?

Comment: Formatting JSON with a prettifier often makes its structure more clear; that would help here

Comment: how many levels do you need to iterate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loops through the object and prints the data to console - you likely did not reach the correct array to loop through.

```
var data = [{
  "offers": [{
    "advertiser_api_id": 12,
    "status": 1
      }, {
    "advertiser_api_id": 13,
    "status": 0
  }]
}];

data[0].offers.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.status);
});
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't go deep enough in that array. Thanks, your code worked :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume this will be in javascript. You can try the following:

```
for (x in json[0].offers) {
    console.log(json[0].offers[x].status);
}
```

Comment: Isn't the offers json in an array, so he would have to do for x in `json[0].offers`?

Answer (score 1):

You have got an array Of Objects inside Array.

Firstly, you need to parse the data from JSON to object using `JSON.parse(data);` Then, access the object `offers`. using the `parsedData[0].offers` object and then iterate over the array to get the status.

```js
var data = `[{
  "offers": [{
    "advertiser_api_id": 12,
    "status": 1
  }, {
    "advertiser_api_id": 13,
    "status": 0
  }]
}]`;

var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
var result = [];
parsedData[0].offers.forEach((currentValue) => result.push(currentValue["status"]));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Actually an array (of objects) _inside an object_ inside an array

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` function:

```js
var data = [{
  "offers": [{
    "advertiser_api_id": 12,
    "status": 1
  }, {
    "advertiser_api_id": 13,
    "status": 0
  }]
}]

var stats = data[0].offers.map(function(item) {
  return item.status;
})

console.log(stats);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
statuses = []
JSON.parse(data)[0].offers.forEach(x => statuses.push(x.status))
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive approach

```
        var item = [{
      "offers": [{
        "advertiser_api_id": 12,
        "status": 1
      }, {
        "advertiser_api_id": 13,
        "status": 0
      }]
    }];

    var statusArray = [];
    function getStatusForALlLevels(item){
     if(item.offers instanceof Array){
     for(var i=0;i<item.offers.length;i++){
      getStatusForALlLevels(item.offers[i]);
      }
     }else{
       statusArray.push(item.status);
     }
    }
    getStatusForALlLevels(item[0]);
    console.log(statusArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach for getting `status` from multiple nested objects.

```js
var data = [{ offers: [{ advertiser_api_id: 12, status: 1 }, { advertiser_api_ii: 13, status: 0 }] }],
    status = data.reduce(function iter(r, o) {
        if ('status' in o) {
            r.push(o.status);
        }
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            if (Array.isArray(o[k])) {
                r = o[k].reduce(iter, r);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(status);
```